# Where does Windows 10 store the emoji font?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, emoji

I am wondering where I can find the font (or set of images) that Windows uses when you select an emoji from the <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> context menu to add to a sentence. Do they come from the default *Segoe UI* font or are they a separate font (or separate files)? One of my other Windows computers appears to have a corrupted emoji file as the majority of them appear as squares like this: `□`, so I was hoping to copy the file from one PC to the other and then install it on the second PC.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by knowing this information?  Yes, it will indeed, help write a better answer

Comment: @Ramhound Updated as per your request.

Comment: Emoji support depends on some kernel support (this is true for other operating systems). Verify both machines are running the exact same version of Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I made sure to update both machines before this so I can guarantee that they are running the same version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a separate font named "Segoe UI Emoji", found in `Windows\Fonts\seguiemj.ttf`.

Comment: Are the images packed in that ttf with color information? Which app can I use to open it?

Comment: More info here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64917/can-truetype-fonts-contain-color

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, user1686 is correct. However, I don't believe that you have a corrupted emoji file. Considering how you have Windows 10, the last emoji update for Windows 10 was in 2019, while every new emoji update **past** that year is only supported in Windows 11. [Click here to see last update that supported emojis for Windows 10.](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-may-2019-update/new/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'd be curious how to fix this problem you describe as well.  I recently received a message in the Windows emoji that said I had TWO files and now half my emojis show up as squares and the other half show the emoji.  That message won't show up again and I didn't write it down.  So I'm guessing I have TWO files that it's trying to read and that's confusing the emoji applet in Windows.  I'd love to fix it.  But have no desire to waste half a day trying to explain the problem to people at Microsoft who don't speak English and don't listen before they try to answer a problem.  Any suggestions how to remove that second file to fix this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1147419)